# Desktop App in C#: Can't get the access token from the embedded webbrowser

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've created a WPF Desktop Application with C# and placed a `System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser`.

Typing this (Where `{0}` is my app id/key)

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?&client_id={0}&response_type=token&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&display=popup&scope=publish_stream,offline_access
```

manually into my firefox/ie/whatever and going to the workflow sends my back to

```
https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html#access_token=TOKEN
```

that's great so far.

But navigating my `System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser` to the workflow redirects this browser to

```
https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html
```

WITHOUT the access token. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with a workaround. The WPF browser cuts off the hash-part of an url, the WinForms webbrowser doesn't.

So watch this code behind of my XAML window which I'm going to use for getting Facebook app permissions from a user:

```
public partial class DiagnosticBrowserWindow : Window
{
    public DiagnosticBrowserWindow(string urlToRequest)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser shadowBrowser = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();

        shadowBrowser.Navigated += (sender, e) =>
        {
            // the access token is now
            // here in e.Url
        };

        this.Browser.Navigated += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (this.Browser.Source.AbsoluteUri.StartsWith("https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html"))
            {
                shadowBrowser.Navigate(urlToRequest);
            }
        };

        this.Browser.Navigate(urlToRequest);
    }
}
```

This is working, because as soon the app permissions have been granted (which we detect by detecting a redirect to login_success.html) we send the shadow browser (which is a WinForms Webbrowser) to the inital request page which is:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?&client_id={0}&response_type=token&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&display=popup&scope=publish_stream,offline_access
```

Facebook will detect, that the permissions already have been granted and send the shadowBrowser back to login_success.html and this time you can read the hash-part.

Answer (score 0):

I hit something like this while implementing [Facebook PowerShell Module](http://facebookpsmodule.codeplex.com). You may be hitting a bug in WPF per http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/discussions/261528. I had to drop back to WinForms for implementing the login capability only. This also fixed an odd crash-on-exit which I had been experiencing.