# no access token on IE8?

Tags: c#, facebook, internet-explorer, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm using C# and the authorization form contains a browser control, which is the system's IE. My request URI is

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=[CLIENT_ID]&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&response_type=token&display=popup&scope=publish_actions
```

On my Windows 7 with IE 9, I can successfully get the access token after the browser is redirected to:

```
https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html#access_token=[ACCESS_TOKEN]
```

However, when the program runs on XP with IE 8, the browser is redirected to :

```
https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html
```

,without access token.

Could anyone tell me why is the difference?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/11307589/255654, this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6159374/255654 and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214731/desktop-app-in-c-cant-get-the-access-token-from-the-embedded-webbrowser

Comment: Thank you! I found the answer in the third link, which is about the fact that the WPF browser cuts off the hash-part of an url